# Notifying a browser about events on server

Tags: get, chat

I have a java based web application(struts 1.2). I have a requirement to display a status on the frontend (jsp). Now the status might change which my server gets notified by another server. But I want this status change to be notified to the browser.

I don't want to make a refresh at intervals. Rather I have to implement something like done in gmail chat, ie. the browser gets notified by changing events on the server.

Any ideas on how to go about this?

I was thinking on lines of opening a request to server for status, and at the server end I would hold the request and wouldn't respond back until there is a status change. Any pointers, examples on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best possible solution will be to make use of XMPP protocol. It's standardized and a lot of open source solutions will get you started within minutes. You can use combination of [Smack](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/), [StropheJS](https://github.com/metajack/strophejs) and [Openfire](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/) to get your java based app work as desired.

Answer (score 1):

There's a method called Long Polling (Comet). It basically sends a request to the server. The request thread created on the server simply waits for new data for the user, with a time limit of maybe 1 minute or more. When new data is available it is returned.

The main problem is to tackle the server-side issue, you don't want to have one thread for every user just waiting for new data. Of course you could use some asynchronous methods depending on your back-end.

Ref: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology

Alternative way would be to use WebSockets. The problem is that it's not supported by all browsers today.